# Editing and saving an existing embedded dictionary using user inputs in tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

[This is where the user will input the new data, and press save for it to be placed into the dictionary where the old data was. I want this to be permanent hopefully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fghn0.png)I have an embedded dictionary defined in my existing code. I also have user inputs to access each individual machine attribute, such as serial #, and then I have a user input area so the users can change what the value of each key is. How do I save the file after the user changed it so it is permanent until the user wants to update it again? I want it to actually change the dictionary.

```
line_7_lst = {
    'Conveyor 701': {'Serial #': "212.3", 'Asset #': '60528', 'Machine Voltage':'none', 'Breaker #': 'none', 'Utility Air Pressure':'none', 'IP Address': 'none', 'HMI Model':'none', 'HMI Program': 'none', 'HMI Battery':'none', 'PLC Model': 'none', 'PLC Program':'none', 'PLC Battery': 'none', 'Additional Notes' : 'None'},


def save_input7():
            (line_7_lst[machine_choice7][attributeinput7]) = user_input7
        line_7_lst
        buttonadd7 = Button(line_7, text="Add", command=save_input7)
        buttonadd7.pack()
        buttonadd7.place(x=1085, y=189)
```

These variables are how I am accessing the dictionary, where I set the dictionary value = to the user input. How do I save this to the dictionary? Is it something I can do with the Json module?

EDIT:
Could I possibly use the shelf module?

Comment: Do you want to save it to `line_7_lst `?

Comment: Yes. I would like the edit to be shown in line_7_lst, or atleast shown as that way when the index is printed.

Comment: You cannot used both pack and place at the same time.. You can comment out either pack or place.